# Liability from selling car if buyer does not complete title transfer : California

Tags: california, liability

Suppose one sells a car (California registered) to a person (suspected after the fact to be an illegal immigrant) who does not complete title-transfer. Suppose that the seller completes and submits the "Notice of Transfer and Release of Liability" https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/online/nrl/welcome . Then, what risks does the seller incur (if any)?

PS: The websites https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/online/nrl/welcome and https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/online/nrl/nrlfaq say:
"Reporting the sale or transfer of a vehicle or vessel to the DMV does not constitute a transfer of ownership. The record is not permanently transferred out of your name until the DMV receives a completed application for transfer of ownership and payment of appropriate fees from the new owner." and "NOTE: In the case of a suit or complaint, the court is responsible for determining if you have complied with the law and are exempt from civil and/or criminal liability." and "NOTE: If any of this information is missing, the department may be unable to update the vehicle record and/or these conditions may disqualify your liability exemption."

Comment: The vehicle would have to be registered as the website says.